# Implement taxometer paywall

Tags: security, web

I need to add a paywall to my site. According to [this article](http://ui-patterns.com/patterns/Paywall), I want to implement a taxometer system. The easiest and least secure way would be tracking the number of viewed articles using secure cookies. But, what if the user deletes the cookie?

I tried to store the data in the backend but I need some sort of connection between my backend the the user's browser. I can't think of anything other than cookies. I know there is a way to do that because NYTimes has improved its paywall system and it works.

I deleted the cookies, session storage and local storage and it still works. I wanna know how they manage to keep track of the browser.

BTW, my backend is python if it helps.

EDIT:

Looks like [browser fingerprinting](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2014/12/01/browser-fingerprints-the-invisible-cookies-you-cant-delete/) is the best way to do it so far. The issue with it is that its javascript based and could be disabled easily.

Comment: IP addresses and user agent sniffing come to mind. But right now it's a little bit unclear whether you're asking "How do I know if this visitor has visited the site X times yet?" or "Where can I find/How do I write a good taxometer system?". The latter is off-topic/too broad, so you may want to edit your question.

Comment: My question is the first one. I wanna know if the a specific user has visited my site more than x times from his browser. It doesn't matter if he changes the browser or uses incognito mode. I wanna limit users per browser.

Comment: But user agent sniffing would not work well on smartphones, right? All iPhone users, having the latest version of chrome would have the same user agent.

Comment: There will never be a perfectly flawless way of doing this; I'm just saying that a combination of IP address tracking, user agent sniffing and cookies can do way better than just cookies (and there's probably not much else you can add to it).